# Does the array_filter function change the given array in place or return a new array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

Does the [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function change the given array in place or return a new array? It's not clear to me from the documentation.

Comment: Just test it. It'd be quicker.

Comment: It modifies the given array and yes its output has to capture in some variable else there won't be any changes in an array.

Comment: Typical __XY problem__ - instead of asking what is really wrong, you ask some non related info about what function does. Please, describe the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the documents:

> Returns the filtered array.

If we compare this with something that just "does" ([ksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)):

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

This is a good indicator of usage. Returning a boolean for an action makes sense, returning data usually implies it's separate from the original variable.

You should do something like:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($el) {return is_int($el);})
```

Answer (score -2):

The `array_filter` function returns a new array and does not change the original array.

I tested the function in a script using PHP version 8.2.7.

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35298294)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The existing answer doesn't explicitly answer the question but instead provides clues from the documentation that indicate what the answer probably is. This is perfectly fine, but I tested the function and found without ambiguity that `array_filter` returns a new array without changes to the original.

As for whether my answer answers the question, it obviously does. The question is whether `array_filter` returns a new array, and my answer is yes.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it

Comment: Nico Haase, I clarified in the answer how I came to the conclusion. I don't understand what other clarification is needed.